# How to connect power BI to a postgresql database on Win10/Ubuntu16 dual-boot system?

Tags: windows, postgresql, ubuntu, powerbi, odoo

For development purposes, I had to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16. So I'm using Win10 for power BI and Ubuntu for odoo development.
Now I have a **local** postgresql database on my Ubuntu that I need to connect to powerBI on windows.
Any idea on how I should do this without having to install a VM?

Comment: Don't install a VM. Use a container. Or just install postgres directly on windows. But you know you can't run two dual boots at a time right? You'll have to get the data off your ubuntu install of postgres and copy it over to windows.

Comment: wouldn't copying the data over to windows make it static ? so does that mean each time I make some changes on the db I have to recopy it ?

Comment: You will not be able to access the db on a dual boot Linux OS while you are running windows from the other dual boot parition. You can't run two dual boots at the same time. Use containers. You'll need to move the db to windows.

Comment: What other things do you need Linux for? YOu can probably conainerise most of them. Or alternatively things like Postgres you can just install straight on to windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking a way to **connect odoo to power BI** then this is what I use for my clients. This connector is **direct connection of powerbi with odoo**.

**https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/bi_direct_connecter/**

*I am currently using their advanced connector which have ability of automatic scheduled refresh. Emailed them for the advanced version.*